# Invalid Country Name for some languages

Tags: java, internationalization, locale, iso

I am trying to print iso countries names in different languages. I am getting correct name for some language however for some I am getting invalid country name (???????)

```
 import java.util.*;
public class LocaleGetDisplayCountryExample2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
// Creating a new Locale
       Locale locale1 = new Locale("sr", "NL");
// Creating another Locale
       Locale locale2 = new Locale("de", "NL");

// Creating another Locale
       Locale locale3 = new Locale("da", "NL");

// display locale
System.out.println("Locale1 name: "+ locale1);
System.out.println("Locale2 name: "+ locale2);
System.out.println("Locale3 name: "+ locale3);

// Use of getDisplayCountry() :
System.out.println("Country Name Locale1: "
                           + locale1.getDisplayCountry(locale1));
System.out.println("Country Name Locale2: "
               + locale2.getDisplayCountry(locale2));

System.out.println("Country Name Locale3: "
               + locale3.getDisplayCountry(locale3));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Locale1 name: sr_NL
Locale2 name: de_NL
Locale3 name: da_NL
Country Name Locale1: ?????????
Country Name Locale2: Niederlande
Country Name Locale3: Netherlands
```

Comment: Isn't "sr" the iso code for serbian language? As far a i know serbian isn't a native language of the netherlands, so sr_NL makes little sense to me.

Comment: What is `sr_NL` supposed to be? What output would you expect and why?

Comment: I am trying to print iso country names in serbian and greek languages,

Comment: I get `Холандија` displayed so it's probably a problem with the encoding of your console

Comment: The fact that this locale makes little sense aside, your output is caused by the fact that you print the country in the supplied language locale. So you are trying to print the serbian name for the Netherlands which would be Холандија. But i suspect whatever you are using to output doesn't support kyrillic characters and therefor you only see ?????

Comment: I guess you'll have the same problem with `Locale locale1 = new Locale("ru", "RU");` right ?

Comment: I have tried eclipse, intelliJ and online compilers, I am getting the same result ???????